# Synergy 1.4.2 Linux server, OSX client, Media/Function key mapping issues

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard, synergy, function-keys

I'm using an Apple bluetooth keybord to control my Linux synergy server.  SSH tunneling, Mouse, Keyboard, and Copy&Paste all work.

Linux sees all the media/app keys that are on top of the F# keys correctly.  However if I press any of those keys while controlling my OSX client, nothing happens on the client.

Running synergys with -d DEBUG1 I can see the following keycode info:
Pressing the "dim monitor" key that also serves as F1 generates:

```
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyPress code=232, state=0x0010
new mask: 0x2000
```

If I press "fn" and the same key, I can see it sending what I'm assuming is an F1:

```
event: KeyPress code=67, state=0x0010
onKeyDown id=61374 mask=0x2000 button=0x0043
send key down to "foo.cisco.com" id=61374, mask=0x2000, button=0x0043
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyRelease code=67, state=0x0010
onKeyUp id=61374 mask=0x2000 button=0x0043
send key up to "foo.cisco.com" id=61374, mask=0x2000, button=0x0043
```

I'm guessing I need to tweak my synergy.conf so that the server sends keys that it currently isn't.  I'm also not sure what I need to do to tweak the keys that it is sending, but are not working.

Below are all the other keys I'm having issues with.  Does anyone have any idea how I can enable their functionality?

brighten monitor:

```
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyPress code=233, state=0x0010
new mask: 0x2000
```

expose:

```
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyPress code=128, state=0x0010
new mask: 0x2000
```

dashboard:

```
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyPress code=212, state=0x0010
new mask: 0x2000
```

dim keyboard:

```
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyPress code=237, state=0x0010
new mask: 0x2000
```

brighten keyboard:

```
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyPress code=238, state=0x0010
new mask: 0x2000
```

rewind:

```
event: KeyPress code=173, state=0x0010
onKeyDown id=57521 mask=0x2000 button=0x00ad
send key down to "foo.cisco.com" id=57521, mask=0x2000, button=0x00ad
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyRelease code=173, state=0x0010
onKeyUp id=57521 mask=0x2000 button=0x00ad
send key up to "foo.cisco.com" id=57521, mask=0x2000, button=0x00ad
```

play/pause:

```
event: KeyPress code=172, state=0x0010
onKeyDown id=57523 mask=0x2000 button=0x00ac
send key down to "foo.cisco.com" id=57523, mask=0x2000, button=0x00ac
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyRelease code=172, state=0x0010
onKeyUp id=57523 mask=0x2000 button=0x00ac
send key up to "foo.cisco.com" id=57523, mask=0x2000, button=0x00ac
```

fastforward:

```
event: KeyPress code=171, state=0x0010
onKeyDown id=57520 mask=0x2000 button=0x00ab
send key down to "foo.cisco.com" id=57520, mask=0x2000, button=0x00ab
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyRelease code=171, state=0x0010
onKeyUp id=57520 mask=0x2000 button=0x00ab
send key up to "foo.cisco.com" id=57520, mask=0x2000, button=0x00ab
```

mute:

```
event: KeyPress code=121, state=0x0010
onKeyDown id=57517 mask=0x2000 button=0x0079
send key down to "foo.cisco.com" id=57517, mask=0x2000, button=0x0079
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyRelease code=121, state=0x0010
onKeyUp id=57517 mask=0x2000 button=0x0079
send key up to "foo.cisco.com" id=57517, mask=0x2000, button=0x0079
```

volume down:

```
onKeyDown id=57518 mask=0x2000 button=0x007a
send key down to "foo.cisco.com" id=57518, mask=0x2000, button=0x007a
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyRelease code=122, state=0x0010
onKeyUp id=57518 mask=0x2000 button=0x007a
send key up to "foo.cisco.com" id=57518, mask=0x2000, button=0x007a
```

volume up:

```
event: KeyPress code=123, state=0x0010
onKeyDown id=57519 mask=0x2000 button=0x007b
send key down to "foo.cisco.com" id=57519, mask=0x2000, button=0x007b
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyRelease code=123, state=0x0010
onKeyUp id=57519 mask=0x2000 button=0x007b
send key up to "foo.cisco.com" id=57519, mask=0x2000, button=0x007b
```

eject:

```
event: KeyPress code=169, state=0x0010
onKeyDown id=57345 mask=0x2000 button=0x00a9
send key down to "foo.cisco.com" id=57345, mask=0x2000, button=0x00a9
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyRelease code=169, state=0x0010
onKeyUp id=57345 mask=0x2000 button=0x00a9
send key up to "foo.cisco.com" id=57345, mask=0x2000, button=0x00a9
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually mapping those keys in your synergy configuration file as per http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html?  From the look of your logs, synergy isn't sending media actions sometimes, and it isn't clear that the ones it is sending are correct.  Try adding

```
section: options
    keystroke(AudioPlay) = keystroke(AudioPlay, mac-screen-name)
end
```

To your synergys configuration file.  If that doesn't work, you could try mapping the hex key-codes directly:

1. Note the codes synergy debug gives you when you push the relevant buttons on your linux box, e.g., 0x00a9 for "eject"
2. Switch the server client relationship (so that your mac is serving) and see what keycode it generates for "eject" (on either its keyboard or the bluetooth--provided the bluetooth keyboard correctly ejects!)
3. Map those keycodes directly:

   ```
   section: options
       keystroke(0x00a9) = keystroke(0x????, mac-screen-name)     # eject
   end
   ```